# JPA2 Hibernate caching

Tags: hibernate

I am trying to execute a simple test using Hibernate as the JPA provider

```
UserDateEntry ude = userService.findById(1000L);
UserDateEntry ude1 = userService.findById(1000L);
```

my findById method looks like this

```
public UserDateEntry findById(Long id) {
    UserDateEntry userDateEntry = entityManager.find(UserDateEntry.class, id);
    return userDateEntry;
}
```

I was expecting only 1 database query. 2nd time around, I thought hibernate should pull the object from persistent context, without hitting the database.

If some body could provide a small working example of configurations required to make this happen, would be very glad.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where and How did you enable the caching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable query caching for this to work. I doesn't see you have configured the caching. Follow the [steps specified here](http://ehcache.org/documentation/hibernate.html).